# Could not access Openseach Serverless Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a serverless open search collection in AWS

The network policy is
Access Type - Public

Resource type -
Access to Opensearch endpoints
Access to Opensearch Dashboards

However, I see OpenSearch Dashboards URL  - Not supported

How can I create/access the open search dashboard for this serverless collection?

Thanks.